# Why does std::timed_mutex::try_lock_for not work?

Tags: c++, c++11

I used gcc-4.8.1(configure: ./configure --prefix=/usr/local) to compile following code in Ubuntu 12.04, but when I ran it, it didn't work. it didn't stop to wait the mutex. It returned false, and outputed "Hello world!"

command: g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -omain -pthread

When I used gcc-4.6(apt-get install g++) to compile it, it worked well. The program waited about ten seconds, and outputed "Hello world!"

> ```
> #include <thread>
> #include <iostream>
> #include <chrono>
> #include <mutex>
>
> std::timed_mutex test_mutex;
>
> void f()
> {
>     test_mutex.try_lock_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
>     std::cout << "hello world\n";
> }
>
> int main()
> {
>     std::lock_guard<std::timed_mutex> l(test_mutex);
>     std::thread t(f);
>     t.join();
>       return 0;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, that is [Bug 54562 -mutex and condition variable timers](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54562).

The reason for the bug is also mentioned:

> This is because it uses the CLOCK_MONOTONIC clock (if available on the
>   platform) to calculate the absolute time when it needs to return,
>   which is incorrect as the POSIX pthread_mutex_timedlock() call uses
>   the CLOCK_REALTIME clock, and on my platform the monotonic clock is
>   way behind the real time clock.

However, this doesn't explain why you see the correct behavior on `gcc-4.6` though. Perhaps `_GLIBCXX_USE_CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is not enabled?

Comment: Thanks, when I disenable _GLIBCXX_USE_CLOCK_MONOTONIC, gcc-4.8 and gcc-4.6 have same behavior. And I think that the reason why they have different behavior is this marco .

Comment: For anyone wanting to upgrade gcc/g++ to 4.9 (where the bug has been fixed), then follow [these instructions](http://superuser.com/a/394811/235047) for Ubuntu, just replacing `4.6` with `4.9`.

Comment: How do you enable _GLIBCXX_USE_CLOCK_MONOTONIC ?

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround:

```
const int WAIT_PRECISION_MS = 10;  // Change it to whatever you like
int TIME_TO_WAIT_MS = 2000;        // Change it to whatever you like
int ms_waited = 0;
bool got_lock = false;
while (ms_waited < TIME_TO_WAIT_MS) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(
                             std::chrono::milliseconds(WAIT_PRECISION_MS));
    ms_waited += WAIT_PRECISION_MS;
    got_lock = YOUR_MUTEX.try_lock();
    if (got_lock) {
        break;
    }
}
```

The `WAIT_PRECISION_MS` will tell the while loop how often to "wake up" and try getting the lock. But, it would also tell how accurate your deadline is going to be, unless your precision time is a factor of the deadline time.

For example:

***deadline = 20, precision = 3***: 3 is not a factor of 20 - the last iteration of the while loop will be when `ms_waited` is 18. It means that you are going to wait a total of 21ms and not 20ms.

***deadline = 20, precision = 4***: 4 is a factor of 20 - the last iteration of the while loop will be when `ms_waited` is 16. It means that you are going to wait exactly 20ms, as your deadline is defined.