# Condition variable wait throws exception

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

The following code throws a std::system_error at the line setupVar.wait. The strange thing is that this happens intermittently - by removing some lines of code, it will run successfully - though not always. Note that this is stripped down from a larger block of code, so all I want it to do is stop and wait.

I am building and running in CentOS 6 using dev-toolset2 (gcc 4.8.2), using the following commands (the code is in the file Test2.cpp):

```
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -pthread -m64 -o"src/Test2.o" "../src/Test2.cpp"
g++ -Wl,--no-as-needed -lpthread -o Test2 ./src/Test2.o
```

The other strange thing is that this works perfectly fine in CentOS 7 (gcc 4.8.5).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Start!!!" << endl;

    bool flag = false;
    std::timed_mutex setupMtx;
    std::condition_variable_any setupVar;

    std::unique_lock<std::timed_mutex> setupLock(setupMtx);

    std::thread theThread(
        [&flag]
        {
            cout << "!!!In thread!!!" << endl;
            flag = true;
        }
    );

    sleep(1);
    setupVar.wait(setupLock);

    theThread.join();

    cout << "!!!End!!!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I run I get:

```
!!!Start!!!
!!!In thread!!!
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Is there anything wrong with the code per se that would cause if to throw an exception at setupVar.wait? Does anyone have any other ideas about what could be causing this problem?

Just for further info, running ldd on the output exe gives:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc37968000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00000034a8c00000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00000034b2c00000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00000034a8800000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00000034b2000000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00000034a8400000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00000034a7c00000)
```

Comment: I tried this code locally on g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609, using same g++ flags as you, and it works fine (it waits after !!!In thread!!!)
so this must be a system specific bug.

Comment: Yes, given that I can also get it to work on CentOS 7 with gcc 4.8.5, that doesn't surprise me. I guess I'll have to switch me effort to putting in different library versions, and possibly a different compiler version, if no-one else has any ideas. Incidentally, if I change the timed_mutex to a plain mutex, and the condition_variable_any to a condition_variable, it works, which leads me to wonder if this isn't a manifestation of [this bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17518464/why-does-stdtimed-mutextry-lock-for-not-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, figured this out in the end, although it was pretty obscure. Just posting on the off-chance that anyone comes across this at a later date.

This is a manifestation of the bug listed at https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2014-1035.html, which is relevant since I have installed the devtoolset-2-gcc package (I actually got mine from CERN) as an easy way to get gcc 4.8 on CentOS 6.

Quoting from above link:

> - Previously, the "std::condition_variable_any" C++11 type was defined
>     incorrectly in GCC. As a consequence, Red Hat Developer Toolset code compiled
>     with a later version of libstdc++ could fail to run on systems with an older
>     version of the library. The header file has been updated and a header-only
>     "condition_variable_any" has been added to be used with a
>     _GLIBCXX_DTS2_CONDITION_VARIABLE_ANY macro. When the macro is defined, compiling
>     works with any version of libstdc++. (BZ#1120929)

Therefore the solution is to define the _GLIBCXX_DTS2_CONDITION_VARIABLE_ANY macro before including condition_variable.